# panel refreshing issues when jcombobox changes in solaris

Tags: java, swing, jtable, solaris, jcombobox

I am having a strange problem, where using a jComboBox is causing screen repaint issues on the portion of the panel below the panel.

Specifically:

I have a panel with a table that is located below a combo box.
(The table has a colored header row)

Opening and closing the combo box (without selecting anything) causes the table header to get colored differently (changes to white).

The region that gets mis-colored is the table cell exactly below the combo box's handle.  (starts at the left side of the cell and stops exactly where the combobox handle stops.)

Resizing the window makes the panel become colored properly.  (which indicates to me that this is a paint problem, as described in: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/swing-135905.html)

Interestingly, it seems to happen only on Solaris (not Linux, have not tried windows).

Apologies in advance for not providing a working example, just looking for ideas at the moment for things to check.

Comment: Example code that we can see, run and test?

Comment: as I said above, "apologies in advance for not providing a working example, just looking for ideas at the moment for things to check."  The code that is exhibiting this problem is by no means simple, and I do not have control over the table or combo box code.  I did make a simple example in the hope it could be added here, but the problem does not occur in the simple example, so obviously something else is contributing to the problem.  Thus the hope that someone might have an idea of things to try.

Comment: I would suspect that you are doing something wrong more then I would suspect that you've come across some bug - IMHO.  If your example can't replicate the problem, I would look into what the differences are between your example and the code that's going astray

Comment: Check whether the Component you're using to paint Colored Header is handling the repaint properly.